# How do I use the URL as a string?

Tags: php

For example:

```
myweb.com/something.php?=hello
                          ^^^
                       Use this string in my code
```

So the string would say `hello`
is this possable?

Comment: Read this http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php there is also examples.

Comment: Hi there. In general it is better to search for what you want, and make an attempt at some code. Here you could search for "PHP query string value" which would be sure to return some useful results. Then, try some code, and ask here if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the user entered http://example.com/?name=Hannes

```
<?php
 echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]) . '!';
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php